# Inserting data from old SQL tables into new tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following Postgres tables

`users` table:

```
 id  |
-----|
```

`user_follows` table (old table):

```
follower_id | following_id
------------|--------------
```

`communities` table (new table):

```
 id  | owner_id
-----|-----------
```

`community_members` table (new table):

```
community_id | member_id
-------------|------------
```

The `communities` already exist each having an `owner_id`. I'm trying to construct a SQL statement that will move data from `user_follows` into `community_members` given a community owner's id. The `following_id` should be the `owner_id` and the `follower_id` should be the `member_id`

`follower_id`, `following_id`, `owner_id`, and `member_id` are all reference to the `users` table `id`.

Thanks!

edit: This is what I'm currently thinking

```
INSERT INTO community_members (community_id, member_id)
SELECT communities.id, user_follows.follower_id
FROM communities JOIN user_follows
WHERE communities.owner_id = 123
AND user_follows.following_id = 123;
``
```

Comment: Have you tried your query? Was there a problem?

Comment: @ADyson I was missing the ON part. It's not a requirement but I'd also like to be able to run this for each community owner instead of having to run individual queries for each one

Comment: Maybe replace the WHERE clause by completing the ON and joining on owner_id and following_id then?

Comment: Oh yes I can see now. You don't need the WHERE clause though, the ON is already implementing that rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The working query is

```
INSERT INTO community_members (community_id, member_id)
SELECT communities.id, user_follows.follower_id
FROM communities JOIN user_follows
ON communities.owner_id = user_follows.following_id
```

It would be cool to be able to do this for every user that is a community owner automatically, instead of having to run the query for each one. This is ok for now as there are <15 users I need to run this for

edit: Have updated to run for all community owners

Comment: That **will do it** for user that is a community owner. There is nothing excluding any community owner therefore it will process every one.